# How to average velocities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

I have a body at motion and I need to calculate it's average velocity
However all the data I got is 2 average velocities
the first from the first half of the time of motion and the secon from the second half how do I calculate their average?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to calculate the average velocity of 2 average velocities](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246790)

Comment: Calculate the total distance traveled, and divide by the total time. Since the time of motion of the two halves are the same, that is a very easy calculation.

Comment: @JohnRennie no - that problem has equal distances; this one has equal times.

Comment: I don't have the distance or the time all I have are veriables that represent the velocities

Comment: Total distance traveled is $v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_2$. Total time is $t_1+t_2$. Divide. Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

This is a "famous" problem for showing what different things "average" can mean.

If "the first half" means half of the time, then your distance will be $(v_1+v_2)*t/2$, and therefore the average velocity just the arithmetical mean $(v_1+v_2)/2$.

If "the first half" means half of the distance, then your time will be $\frac{s/2}{v_1} + \frac{s/2}{v_2}$, and therefore the average velocity the so-called harmonical mean: $$v = \frac{s}{\frac{s/2}{v_1} + \frac{s/2}{v_2}} = \frac 2{\frac 1{v_1} + \frac 1{v_2}}$$

Comment: For students starting on a serious study of physics it is worth taking note of the harmonic mean: you'll be seeing it again from time to time in other contexts.